# How to interpret the student t statistic in a sas proc univariate output

Tags: t-test, sas, univariate

I ran a proc univariate on a SAS data set and one of the output results was:

```
Test           -Statistic-    -----p Value------
Student's t    t  73.93231    Pr > |t|    <.0001
```

How should I interpret this? Does it mean that the probability that an observation will be > 73.93 is very small (< .0001)

Comment: Almost right, it would be better if you say "under the null hypothesis, the probability that the *t-statistic* (not the original observation)..."

Comment: Thanks. But exactly is the null hypothesis ? I didn't specify any? Did proc univariate come up with a null hypothesis on its own?